# What is the correct way of implementing this custom priority_queue

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I want to build a priority queue of an object having three elements having my own comparator. I tried the following code but is showing error .

---

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


class triplet {
    public:    
        int data;
        int arr;
        int index;       
};

bool compare( triplet x, triplet y ){

    if(x.data < y.data){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

int main(){

 priority_queue<triplet,vector<triplet>,compare> pq1;

}
```

---

getting the following error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZRAH.png)

Comment: What error are you getting, and what headers are you including?  [Edit] your question to include these details.

Comment: Your code doesn't [remotely compile](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/824f7d6be7a02204). Post a [mcve] as required here please!

Comment: Also read up here please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h Stop doing this, especially in combination with `using namespace std;`. Who taught you to do so?

Comment: Ok I got your point but the problem here is not which header file I am using , can you please explain how the priority_queue can be implemented.

Comment: @KundanKumar Not to mention that your question title isn't useful for future research.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` - *Never*, *ever*, do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparison routines must return false if the two elements are equal, but your version returns true.

Try this instead

```
bool compare(triplet x, triplet y) {

    if (x.data < y.data) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

or to make it a little simpler like this

```
bool compare(triplet x, triplet y) {    
    return x.data < y.data;
}
```

But the important point is `<` not `<=`.

**EDIT**

Your code also uses `compare` incorrectly. `compare` is not a type, so it's not a valid argument for the priority_queue template.

The type of `compare` is `bool (*)(triplet, triplet)` so the right way to do this is to use that type in the template and pass the actual comparison function to the constructor. Like this

```
priority_queue<triplet, vector<triplet>, bool (*)(triplet, triplet)> pq1(compare);
```

BTW normally you would do this by creating a comparison *functor*, not a function. It's a little cleaner that way (and potentially more efficient).

Comment: I changed that also but still it is showing the same error.

Comment: @KundanKumar OK, I missed that error (you hadn't posted the error message when I replied). I'll edit my answer.